# how to find the particular service name using If statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, aws-sdk, boto3

i am new to the python boto3 function in AWS. I want to know how to search for particular serviceNameArn `(u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-selenium-node-chrome-service-Service-5ZADFVZNNCFJ)` among the list of services running in the AWS ECS cluster that i have below with the key value pair: {"Browser":"Chrome"}.

here is my code:

```
import boto3
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify, make_response
import requests
import json

browser='chrome'
CLUSTER = 'ECS-QEAUTOMATION-HYBRID-DEV'
client = boto3.client('ecs')
list_services = client.list_services(cluster=CLUSTER)
print(list_services['serviceArns'])
for x in list_services:
    if browser in x:
        x.servicename
        print(x.servicename)
```

Output:
I am still receiving the list of all services running in the cluster except one:

```
[u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-selenium-hub-service-Service-1ESSGHC030KT6', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-selenium-node-chrome-service-Service-5ZADFVZNNCFJ', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-sonarqube-service-Service-1359LNU242V25', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-jmetermaster-service-Service-1JOAYPCN8KNZI', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-jmeterslave-service-Service-1PIAW69QGP9F8', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-selenium-node-firefox-service-Service-QVDLJQ423TX7', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-dashboard-service-Service-1T8VSPQ28ZAGO', u'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:778784494011:service/RITS-commandcenter-service-Service-1MVRK6EPDL3MN']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It looks like you were looping through list_services instead of the arns.

```
browser='chrome'
CLUSTER = 'ECS-QEAUTOMATION-HYBRID-DEV'
client = boto3.client('ecs')
list_services = client.list_services(cluster=CLUSTER)
service_arns = list_services['serviceArns']
print(service_arns )
for service_arn in service_arns:
    if browser in service_arn:
        print(service_arn)
```

Comment: Thanks @Branson, but it seems that it's going to check whether 'browser' Arns is available inside the list_of_services. If yes, then it will print all the Arns. I want to print only 'browser' Arns  .. Thanks in advance !